# Change statusBar background color while using large title for navigation bar on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

I'm trying to use the new navigationBar's large title feature on iOS 11.

However, after I added the following line:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

I found that the navigationBar background color changed to black.

[image: Navigation Bar 1]

So I set background color again manually:

```
self.navigationController?.setBackgroundColor(UIColor(hexString: 0xFF7E79))
```

However, I found that the statusBar background color didn't change:

[image: Navigation Bar 2]

After I set up the background color of statusBar through this code:

```
guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return 
statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: 0xFF7E79)
```

It gives me an ugly 1px black line like this between the statusBar and the navigationBar:

[image: Navigation Bar 3]

So what is the correct way to set the background color of navigationBar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to set the background color of the `UINavigationBar` is to use the `barTintColor` property.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
```

You may notice that the color you set can be a little faded. As noted in the documentation:

> This color is made translucent by default unless you set the `isTranslucent` property to `false`.

[See the barTintColor reference on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624931-bartintcolor)